# array's base address

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I was going through a book where I found this question

Does mentioning the array name gives the base address in all the contexts?

Can some one explain the cases where array name does not give the base address.thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[C 2011 online draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

> #### 6.2.3.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators
>
> 3 Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the
>  unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has
> type ‘‘array of *type*’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to *type*’’ that points
>                to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object has
>               register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

So, given a declaration like

```
int a[N];
```

the following expressions do *not* convert the expression `a` to a pointer type:

```
sizeof a
_Alignof a
&a
```

Given the following declarations

```
char str[] = "This is a test";
char *p    = "This is another test";
```

the string literal `"This is a test"` is being used to initialize an array of `char`, so it will not be converted to a pointer expression; instead, the contents of the array will be copied to `str`.  In contrast, the string literal `"This is another test"` is *not* being used to initialize an array, so it is converted to a pointer expression, and the value of the pointer is written to `p`.

Answer (score 5):

Array-to-pointer decay does not happen everywhere. One example is the argument of `sizeof`, another is the argument of `&`:

```
int arr[10];

sizeof(arr);          // gives 10 * sizeof(int), NOT sizeof(int*)

int (*p)[10] = &arr;  // gives the address of the array, NOT of an rvalue
```

The second example is fairly obvious, since the value of the array-to-pointer decay is not-an-lvalue, so it wouldn't make sense any other way.

Comment: I think a simple `int *p = &arr;` would get the job done too.

Answer (score 2):

One such context is the `sizeof` operator, where `sizeof(array)` gives the (byte) size of the array.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: I don't understand your objection. `sizeof` is indeed a context in which there is no array-to-pointer decay.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: The question is "explain the cases where array name does not give the base address". Inside the `sizeof` operator, the array name doesn't give its base address, period.

Comment: I was too fast, sorry, undoing the -1.

Answer (score 2):

Array name give address of first element:

int a = {1,2,3};

Suppose address of a is 12

printf(" %u %u",a,&a);

result is

12 12

Where a is address of first element and &a is address of array. same value but different semantic

printf(" %u %u", a+1, &a+1);

result is

14 18

a increased by 2 because 'a' is address of integer and a+1 increase by 2  that is sizeof(int)

where as &a+1 increate by size of array that is 3 int = 3 * sizeof(int)

Assuming sizeof int is 2

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: Thanks will do next time onwards.... but this time  I wants to show in unsigned number and less complex too!

Comment: Then cast the pointer to `unsigned int`. I mean, `if sizeof(int) != sizeof(void*)`, which is usually the case in 64-bit code, `printf()` may get very upset.